# Conversations class in Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

I try to pass to my view sample  Blade the result of a method that is in:

App / Conversations / bot.php

```
private function searchCompatibility()
{
    $users = Products::all();

    return View::make('sample')->with('products', $products);
}
```

In my routes I want to send the result of my method to my view, how can I send it to call, what is the correct syntax? Or can it only be from a controller?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared $users and you pass $products in your return statement

Change the variable `$users` to `$products`

Answer (score 0):

You wrongly define your variable. you define $users but you pass as $product

```
private function searchCompatibility()
{
    $products = Products::all();

    return view('sample', compact('products'));
}
```